# Conversation ID leads to unkown path in graph-api

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I have a code that fetches conversations and the messages inside them (a specific number of pages). It works most of the time, but for certain conversations it throws an exception, such as:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Unknown path components: /[id of the message]/messages (code 2500, subcode null)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1192)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1118)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1059)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:970)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:932)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchConnection(DefaultFacebookClient.java:356)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:40)
```

After debugging I found the ID that doesn't work and tried to access it from graph-api, which results in an "unknown path components" error. I also attempted to manually find the conversation in me/conversations and click the next page link in the graph api explorer which also lead to the same error.

Is there a different way to retrieve a conversation than by ID? And if not, could someone show me an example to verify first if the conversation ID is valid, so if there are conversations I can't retrieve I could skip them instead of getting an error. Here's my current  code:

```
Connection<Conversation> fetchedConversations = fbClient.fetchConnection("me/Conversations", Conversation.class);

    int pageCnt = 2;

    for (List<Conversation> conversationPage : fetchedConversations) {

        for (Conversation aConversation : conversationPage) {
            String id = aConversation.getId();

            //The line of code which causes the exception
            Connection<Message> messages = fbClient.fetchConnection(id + "/messages", Message.class, Parameter.with("fields", "message,created_time,from,id"));

            int tempCnt = 0;
            for (List<Message> messagePage : messages) {
                for (Message msg : messagePage) {
                    System.out.println(msg.getFrom().getName());
                    System.out.println(msg.getMessage());
                }
                if (tempCnt == pageCnt) {
                    break;
                }
                tempCnt++;

            }
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update**: Surrounded the problematic part with a try catch as a temporary solution, also counted the number of occurrences and it only effects 3 out of 53 conversations. I also printed all the IDs, and it seems that these 3 IDs are the only ones that contain a "/" symbol, I'm guessing it has something to do with the exception.

The IDs that work look something like this: t_[text] (sometimes a "." or a ":" symbol) and the ones that cause an exception are always t_[text]/[text]

Answer (score 0):

conv_id/messages is not a valid graph api call.
messages is a field of conversation.

Here is what you do (single call to api):

```
Connection<Conversation> conversations = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/conversations", Conversation.class);

                    for (Conversation conv : conversations.getData()) {

                       // To get list of messages for given conversation
                       LinkedList<Message> allConvMessagesStorage = new LinkedList<Message>();

                       Connection<Message> messages25 = facebookClient.fetchConnection(conv.getId()+"/messages", Message.class);

                     //Add messages returned
                     allConvMessagesStorage.addAll(messages25.getData());
                       //Check if there is next page to fetch
                       boolean progress = messages25.hasNext();
                       while(progress){
                          messages25 = facebookClient.fetchConnectionPage(messages25.getNextPageUrl(), Message.class);
                          //Append next page of messages
                          allConvMessagesStorage.addAll(messages25.getData());
                       progress = messages25.hasNext();
        }


                    }
```

Comment: This way getMessages() returns 25 messages then the loop moves on to the next conversation. For my program I'm going to need to be able to get more than the last 25 messages of each conversation.

Comment: sorrry I missed that. Corrected the answer

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately though your answer causes the same exception 
my original code does at the fetchConnection(conv.getId() ... line.

The exception is the same:

"Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Unknown path components: /L1wPnlP6fqufduA/messages (code 2500, subcode null)"



Maybe there's something gone wrong on my side with that couple of IDs and there's not much to do about it? This only occurs with 3 out of 53 conversations and these IDs all have "/" symbol in them,the others don't.

Comment: if a conversation id has a "/" symbol in it, there is something wrong and you should open a bug on Facebook.